# How to get resource in tests using Gradle?

Tags: testing, resources, gradle, spock

I have:

```
--src
-----main
-----test
--------resources
-------------test.zip
```

In test directory I have Spock test. How can I refer the test.zip file so to pass its absolute path to the test and to check some of my methods? I tried with **new File('.').absolutePath** but I want to find better solution

```
def "check checkTypeZipMethod"() {
        expect:
        assert testedMethod(new File('.').absolutePath+"test/resources/test.zip")==true

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either try to locate the zip file based on `ClassLoader#getResource`, or configure the `test` task to set a system property pointing to the zip file. The latter is easier to implement, but harder to make work in environments other than Gradle (e.g. when running the test inside an IDE).

PS: In a Spock `expect:` or `then:` block, you can (and should) omit the `assert` keyword.